# How to average monthly data using a specific method in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following vector of monthly values (vectorA). I put the date related info next to it to help illustrate the task but I work with just the vector itself

```
dates         month_in_q   vectorA          
31/01/2020       1           10          
29/02/2020       2           15            
31/03/2020       3           6 
30/04/2020       1           8
31/05/2020       2           4
30/06/2020       3           3
```

How can I create a new vectorNEW according to this algorithm

- In each quarter the first month is the original first month
- In each quarter the second month is the average of first and second month
- In each quarter the third month is the average of all three months

So that I get the following vectorNEW by manipulating the original vectorA in a loop given this the re-occuring pattern above

```
dates         month_in_q   vectorA   vectorNEW       
31/01/2020       1           10          10
29/02/2020       2           15          AVG(10+15)  
31/03/2020       3           6           AVG(10+15+6)
30/04/2020       1           8           8
31/05/2020       2           4           AVG(8+4)
30/06/2020       3           3           AVG(8+4+3)
...              ...        ...          ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant solution was provided by the user dpb on mathworks website.

```
vectorNEW=reshape(cumsum(reshape(vectorA,3,[]))./[1:3].',[],1);
```

Further info below

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/823055-how-to-average-monthly-data-using-a-specific-method-in-matlab